# Show that $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\int_{S_r}u(x,y)ds =0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Show that for all $0<\rho\leq r$ $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\int_{S_r}u(x,y)ds =0$.Well, the hypotesis is $u$ is harmonic ($\Delta u=0$) , $0\in \Omega$,and $B_{\rho}$ the ball with radios, $\rho>0$ $B_{\rho}\subset \Omega$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ is a unitary radial vector, $S_r$ circle with center in origin. Iam not sure how to star, i need to show that the integral is a constant respect to $r$, i know that the derivate can be introduce under integral sign because $u$ is of class $C^2$ and $S_r$ is compact set(close and bounded in $R^n$) but what can i do? The other side i try to do parts integration but i need to put other function $v$ that let zero on the boundary, but dont go anywhere? Can you help me with a hint please? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer is that this is automatically zero by the spherical mean-value property of harmonic functions. However, this fact is generally used to prove the spherical mean-value property, so let's do it directly.

First for simplicity let's define $\phi(r) = \frac{1}{r^{n - 1}}\int_{S_r} u(x) dS(x)$. Here $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $dS(x)$ represents the surface measure with respect to varying $x$ (the proof is no different in 2D than in $n$D). The first step is realizing that it's hard to take derivatives when the variable is in the limit of integration, so the first thing to do would be to reparametrize the integral via a change of variables to get the $r$ out of the limits and into the integrand. The standard choice is to integrate over the unit sphere. This gives, by changing variables $x \mapsto ry$ for $y \in S_1$,
$$
\phi(r) = \int_{S_1}u(ry)dS(y).
$$
(Where did the factor of $r^{n - 1}$ go?) Then take a derivative using the chain rule.

Comment: The $dS(y)r^{n-1}=dx$ right?

Comment: Excusme, What happen with $Du(ry)y=Du(ry)$ why is zero? And where i use that $\Delta u=0$ thank you Chris

Comment: Perfect so you get $Du(ry)\cdot y$ in the integrand now. But since we are integrating over the unit sphere $S_1$, it so happens that $y \in S_1$, the variable of integration, IS the unit normal vector to the region of integration! So we can use the fact that integrating a vector field $X$ dot a unit normal over the boundary of a region is the integral of the divergence over the interior of the region. Then use that the divergence of the gradient is the laplacian

Comment: You mean $ div (\nabla u)=\Delta u=0$ but is happen on the ball complete!! Thank you Chris